# Suggestion for wearable EEG headset

Tags: measurement, eeg, brain-computer-interface

We need wearable EEG headset with raw data output accessible from various platforms. I heard that devices like that have commonly the output encoded and available adapters are designed for one or just few platforms.

What we really prefer is device with output with standard (or well known) protocol, so we can create our own adapters.

Do you know what EEG wearable headset is the best for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Emotiv EPOC+ Research Edition can be used on Windows, Linux and Mac.

It has 14 electrodes (+2 reference electrodes) and is used in several publicized studies. 
You can access raw data via their software "Testbench" and output it as CSV or use third party software like OpenVibe, BCI2000 and EEGLab.

But the little drawbacks are:

- It is a wireless device, so you really should put the usb dongle for wireless signal transmission with a long usb cable directly on the device, to overcome signal distortion
- The reference electrode processing is done within the device
- It seems to be more intended for consumer use than for medical use

**EDIT about realtime usage of EPOC+ and OpenVibe Software:**

There are studies and projects using the EPOC+ in realtime with OpenVibe. OpenVibe has a built in driver for the EPOC+ Research Edition

https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiz2c-FpuXJAhVBhA8KHY0tD-IQFghbMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mtg.upf.edu%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Fpublications%2FSergio%2520Giraldo%2520-%2520Brain-Activity-Driven%2520Real-Time%2520Music%2520Emotive%2520Control.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEi0w9wT2eMlUUxvUyLj2jsKL1ewg&sig2=eJMv2T_OjE4tHr6JnbV4IA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.ZWU

And in this project two devices can be used, the EPOC+ and the the ***Enobio***, which seems to be an intersting device, too. But I do not have enough knowledge about the Enobio to recommend it. But it might be even better as the EPOC+, as they have models with more electrodes. This is the realtime application for the two devices:
https://github.com/marcelfarres/Play_Your_Mood

By the way, OpenVibe features drivers for quite some EEGs, but it can only be used on Windows and Linux. On Mac you would have to compile it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I know EPOC+ and according to discussion https://github.com/openyou/emokit/issues/138 it seems that currently it is impossible to read data in real-time without their software. It seems nobody understands the way how they send data from device to pc. So it seems to be useless for research, we cannot make our own adapter. Also their pricing for device, license?! and raw data software?! (without proper explanation) does not make me happy. If I am incorrect in my opinion or informations, please tell me.

Comment: Two more links that i could not post into my edit above, as i am limited due to my amount of reputation:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262288467_Detecting_emotion_from_EEG_signals_using_the_emotive_epoc_device

OpenVibe Devices:
http://openvibe.inria.fr/supported-hardware/

Comment: Thank you for information about OpenVibe, but it seems that it is application using the official adapter from emotiv, so it is still not solution for us. What we really want is headset for what we can create our own adapter - it seems that this is impossible for emotiv now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [OpenBCI](http://www.openbci.com/)?

[image]

You can view their latest kickstarter here:

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/openbci/openbci-biosensing-for-everybody

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I have not found how to communicate with this device without their software.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Brain Monitoring has amazing high quality EEG systems that are almost as good as medical grade equipment (Reference will follow).

There are several choices you can make. There is the X-10 (9 channels plus mastoid and ECG), the X-24 (20 channels plus mastoid and ECG). Each of these systems also have accelerometers integrated. Moreover, ABM has a sleep profiler, an even simpler EEG system with fewer channels. ABM also provides neat online and offline analysis software. Definitely recommend it.

Other possibilities are the Nexus systems and Biopac Mobita. I haven't worked with them but they exist.